# A problem of complex numbers from my coursebook

Tags: complex-numbers

I have solved a, b, d, e and the first part of c but just can't seem to do second part of c.
[image]

**NOTE : To let someone in the future search the same question, I will also add the first few lines of question. The full question is given in the picture above.**
A , B and C are points in an Argand diagram representing the complex numbers -1 + 0 i ,
1+0 i and 0 + i respectively, and P is the point representing the complex number z (with Im(z)>0)

Comment: You can answer your own question and it is encouraged on this site. Just remember to use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) instead of images as images cannot be searched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: write it as $\,zz^*+z-z^*-1 = i(zz^*-z+z^*-1)\,$ then equate the real parts on the two sides, using that $\,zz^* \in \mathbb R\,$ and $\,z-z^* \in i\,\mathbb R\,$.

Comment: Tried it, maybe did something wrong but zz* just cancels out

Comment: Hey, tried it again and bingo solved it, I split z = a + ib and used the hint you gave and it was solved. Thanks!

Comment: @SamipGyawali You don't need to explicitly split it, just $\text{Re}\big(zz^*+\underbrace{z-z^*}_{= \,2\, i\, \text{Im}(z)}-1\big) = zz^*-1\,$ and $\,\text{Re}\big(i(zz^*-z+z^*-1)\big)=\dots\,$

Comment: Oh yeah I got it now, what i did was much longer, thanks again!